# no sound playing old quicktime videos on windows 7

Tags: audio, quicktime

I have an old video (2005) that doesn't play sound but actually it did before!

I don't understand why. I downloaded QuickTime player 7.7.6 but still nothing.

Please, anybody help me

Comment: What type of video file are you having trouble with?

Comment: It is QuickTime Video File named "oldvideo.MOV"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the K-Lite codec pack, make sure you install all audio related packages: [Link](http://filehippo.com/download_klite_codec_pack)